# Java Applet would load only once (in the first window) in Internet Explorer

Tags: applet, internet-explorer, java

I am in a bit of fix here. In my company, we have a local intarnet website which has a menu bar in the form of an applet. Few days ago i remember i downloaded an update (either JRE or Windows , i can't recall) and after that in IE strange behavior is observed w.r.t the menu bar applet loading.

If i open the web page first time, the applet would load. when i open a second IE window or tab, the web page would load but the applet just wouldn't load. No Errors, nothing just white space in stead of menu bar applet. If i refresh multiple time, some time the applet would load by itself. purely random behaviour. When i open the website in google chrome, everything works fine. If i open java console, no errors are displayed i.e. the java is just failing to load at all !!!!

I downgraded IE 8 to IE 7 and IE 6 and uninstalled , reinstalled JRE and tried all combinations but the problem still exists !!

Please advice.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Trying another browser might shed some light on the situation. Also, clear you Java Plugin's cache, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011010/java-applet-deployment-classnotfoundexception-primary-class/3011022#3011022

Answer (score 0):

yes i did try clearing cach but the problem persists. i mean its purely random. the first time the applet always loads. after that some times it doesn some times it doesn't. No errors at all. Now even google chrome is crashing when ever i open the website saying Data execution prevention error.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Java console, and enable all logging for it.  THis will allow you to see what is actually going on and may allow you to determine why the applet fails.