# classNotFoundException when including applet un html file

Tags: java, html, applet

I've follow a lot of tutos and forum exemple and i've always the same problem.

I've generated a jar file from an applet in netbeans, including class files from my project.
My main class (containing the init() method) is in the package caiusapplet and is named CaiusWeb.

My jar file and my html file are in the same directory, and there is the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
       <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       </head>
       <body>
          <applet code="caiusapplet.CaiusWeb" archive="CaiusApplet.jar">
          </applet>
       </body>
    </html>
</pre>
```

But I always have the same issue :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: caiusapplet.CaiusWeb.
```

Could you please help me?

### Edit 1 :

I've change my html code to

```
<OBJECT width="200" height="200" data="caiusapplet/CaiusWeb.class" type="application/x-java-applet">
        <PARAM name="code" value="caiusapplet/CaiusWeb.class">
</OBJECT>
```

I've now another error message :

Exception : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

What's the matter ?
Thanks

### Edit 2 :

I've found what was wrong : there was a JFileChooser in my java code. I removed it : everything is working. So now : What's wrong with the JFileChooser and the applet : access rights ? Still trying... Tanks for your help, if you can say to me how work with JFileChooser... I'll be very grateful !

### Edit 3 :

That's ok, if you have the same problem :
Create au jar file manually from your .class files ans sign it, everything's now ok !
Thaks a lot.

Comment: Uh. What happend to my edits?

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011010/java-applet-deployment-classnotfoundexception-primary-class

Comment: Get it working with the `applet` element in plain HTML 1st up.  Speaking of which, the HTML/applet combo. shown first in this thread, is both invalid & malformed.  Be sure to check the HTML using a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) & fix all errors before spending time trying to debug the load/display in this or that browser.

Comment: Done. The valid html document, using object tag, is nevertheless still not working : InvocationTargetException.

Comment: *"The valid html document, using object tag,.."* Which part of *"Get it working with the `applet` element" do you not understand?  I am willing to give applet HTML a close scrutiny.  BTW - the `object` code shown specifies no archives, while the `applet` element is still showing as completely invalid.  Drop the `object` attempts at the moment and show me some amended, valid `applet` element.

Answer (score 0):

This exception fires when required class in not in matching path on unavailable, may be you are forget to add that particular class into jar.

Comment: Here is the liste of the files that are in my jar file : in the sub directory "caiusapplet" -> CaiusWeb.class